# cardio workout : grading and fat loss efficacy

Tags: weight-loss, workout, cardio, body-fat, obesity

I weighed 331bs.  For last 10+ yrs struggling against obesity. 
For quite sometime I had been doing cardo 1 hr daily . Here are my questions

- I read someplace in the past that low intensity - prolonged cardios cause muscle mass depletion at the cost of preserving fat. Now being morbidly obese   ( currently I am at  317lbs from 330lbs . 325-330 would be my weight if I just ate whatever I felt & did 0 workout ) , I had not ventured out to run on the treadmill  but instead I increase the elevation to 9-10 ( I think 14 is Highest ) & walk at lower speeds ( 4.6 compared to what most people run on around 8+ speed ) . I assured this is not "low intensity" cos I SWEAT  all over ( even with 3 AC's on  in that room ) . I think my heart rate would easily be 90-100 while I did that. Does this fit into the "low Intensity"  cutout ?  ( I do this for 60 mins daily. With breaks .  During the breaks I will do sit ups around 2--30 totally ) 

   (  Off recently I started running on the tread-mill but I can barely manage 1 min at a time before I start panting- so I  increase my walking pace to around 4.9-5 and reduced the incline from 9-10 to 6.5-7 and I try and give more frequent 1 min sprints  around 4 mins running in a 60 mins work out )
- In-spite of that I see the weight increases or remains status quo but wont go down. I wonder if this muscle mass depletion at the cost of fat preservation. Before you tell me it is - and hit me with the "oh you got it totally wrong" stick -consider the fact that fat loss should cause extremely slow weight reduction as compared to muscle mass depletion. Fat is lighter and floats compared to muscle. So  coming to my weight gain/ constant weight - problem. What seems to happen here. I am frustrated.. Should I continue on this path or change. In the past I had bounced between 302lbs to 330lbs but this kind of exercise would made me consistently loose weight EVEN when I did not diet seriously just because It made me sweat. My age has advanced (43) and I do dieting and cardio. Same / more intense work out + some kinda diet control - no weight loss. I  guess a direct way would be to buy those body fat scales - what changed muscle mass , water etc . I DID . But it will  (its  one from Amazon  - EatSmart  body scale ) error out after reading my weight , which it does apparently correctly  ( for someone who is 200lbs it works well )

Comment: Walking is the best form of cardio you can do - it is awesome for fat loss and your joints will thank you. Weight loss is a long road and you might not see it on scale, but you will see it in the mirror. I would keep walking, 4-7km a day is the distance you should be aiming for. Check your calories with myfitnesspal and you will look awesome in no time. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

Just seriously restrict calories intake, what kind of exercises you are doing is not that important, it's about calorie restriction